# i have to convert an xml file to csv in php but it has to have a specific looking output

Tags: php, xml, csv

sorry if the post is constructed poorly, I'm new to all of this and am still learning.

from my understanding, the first row has to be the tags names and the second row, their values.
Since I'm a beginner it's really hard to wrap my head around how to take that array and fit it into one row in one cell.
from my output, the first 10 rows should also not be there, but I have no clue how to skip them when making the array.

This is the PHP code that I used for the result:

```
<?php
$xmlraw = 'plik_wejsciowy.xml';
   
if (file_exists($xmlraw)) {
      
    $xml_content = simplexml_load_file($xmlraw);
      
    $a = fopen('plik_wyjściowy.csv', 'w');
      
    Csv($xml_content, $a);
      
    fclose($a);
}
  
    function Csv($xml_content, $a)
    {
        foreach ($xml_content->children() as $item) {
            $hasChild = (count($item->children()) > 0) ? true : false;
            if (!$hasChild) {
                $array = array($item->getName(), $item);
                fputcsv($a, $array, ',','"');
            } else {
                Csv($item, $a);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

This is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<JPK xmlns:tns="http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2021/12/27/11149/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:etd="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2021/06/08/eD/DefinicjeTypy/" xsi:schemaLocation="http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2021/12/27/11149/schemat.xsd">
    <Naglowek>
        <KodFormularza kodSystemowy="JPK_V7K (2)" wersjaSchemy="1-0E">JPK_VAT</KodFormularza>
        <WariantFormularza>2</WariantFormularza>
        <DataWytworzeniaJPK>2022-01-01T00:00:00Z</DataWytworzeniaJPK>
        <NazwaSystemu>a</NazwaSystemu>
        <CelZlozenia poz="P_7">2</CelZlozenia>
        <KodUrzedu>1430</KodUrzedu>
        <Rok>2022</Rok>
        <Miesiac>1</Miesiac>
    </Naglowek>
    <Podmiot1 rola="Podatnik">
        <OsobaFizyczna>
            <etd:NIP>1010000000</etd:NIP>
            <etd:ImiePierwsze>a</etd:ImiePierwsze>
            <etd:Nazwisko>a</etd:Nazwisko>
            <etd:DataUrodzenia>1900-01-01</etd:DataUrodzenia>
            <Email>!@"</Email>
            <Telefon>a</Telefon>
        </OsobaFizyczna>
    </Podmiot1>
    <Ewidencja>
        <SprzedazWiersz>
            <LpSprzedazy>1</LpSprzedazy>
            <KodKrajuNadaniaTIN>BB</KodKrajuNadaniaTIN>
            <NrKontrahenta>a</NrKontrahenta>
            <NazwaKontrahenta>a</NazwaKontrahenta>
            <DowodSprzedazy>a</DowodSprzedazy>
            <DataWystawienia>2006-01-01</DataWystawienia>
            <DataSprzedazy>2006-01-01</DataSprzedazy>
            <TypDokumentu>WEW</TypDokumentu>
            <GTU_01>1</GTU_01>
            <WSTO_EE>1</WSTO_EE>
            <IED>1</IED>
            <TP>1</TP>
            <TT_WNT>1</TT_WNT>
            <TT_D>1</TT_D>
            <MR_T>1</MR_T>
            <MR_UZ>1</MR_UZ>
            <I_42>1</I_42>
            <I_63>1</I_63>
            <B_SPV>1</B_SPV>
            <B_SPV_DOSTAWA>1</B_SPV_DOSTAWA>
            <B_MPV_PROWIZJA>1</B_MPV_PROWIZJA>
            <KorektaPodstawyOpodt>1</KorektaPodstawyOpodt>
            <TerminPlatnosci>2016-01-01</TerminPlatnosci>
            <K_10>0</K_10>
            <SprzedazVAT_Marza>0</SprzedazVAT_Marza>
        </SprzedazWiersz>
        <SprzedazWiersz>
            <LpSprzedazy>2</LpSprzedazy>
            <KodKrajuNadaniaTIN>CC</KodKrajuNadaniaTIN>
            <NrKontrahenta>b</NrKontrahenta>
            <NazwaKontrahenta>b</NazwaKontrahenta>
            <DowodSprzedazy>b</DowodSprzedazy>
            <DataWystawienia>2006-01-01</DataWystawienia>
            <DataSprzedazy>2006-01-01</DataSprzedazy>
            <TypDokumentu>WEW</TypDokumentu>
            <GTU_01>1</GTU_01>
            <WSTO_EE>1</WSTO_EE>
            <IED>1</IED>
            <TP>1</TP>
            <TT_WNT>1</TT_WNT>
            <TT_D>1</TT_D>
            <MR_T>1</MR_T>
            <MR_UZ>1</MR_UZ>
            <I_42>1</I_42>
            <I_63>1</I_63>
            <B_SPV>1</B_SPV>
            <B_SPV_DOSTAWA>1</B_SPV_DOSTAWA>
            <B_MPV_PROWIZJA>1</B_MPV_PROWIZJA>
            <KorektaPodstawyOpodt>1</KorektaPodstawyOpodt>
            <TerminPlatnosci>2016-01-01</TerminPlatnosci>
            <K_10>0</K_10>
            <SprzedazVAT_Marza>0</SprzedazVAT_Marza>
        </SprzedazWiersz>
        <SprzedazWiersz>
            <LpSprzedazy>3</LpSprzedazy>
            <KodKrajuNadaniaTIN>DD</KodKrajuNadaniaTIN>
            <NrKontrahenta>c</NrKontrahenta>
            <NazwaKontrahenta>c</NazwaKontrahenta>
            <DowodSprzedazy>c</DowodSprzedazy>
            <DataWystawienia>2006-01-01</DataWystawienia>
            <DataSprzedazy>2006-01-01</DataSprzedazy>
            <TypDokumentu>WEW</TypDokumentu>
            <GTU_01>1</GTU_01>
            <WSTO_EE>1</WSTO_EE>
            <IED>1</IED>
            <TP>1</TP>
            <TT_WNT>1</TT_WNT>
            <TT_D>1</TT_D>
            <MR_T>1</MR_T>
            <MR_UZ>1</MR_UZ>
            <I_42>1</I_42>
            <I_63>1</I_63>
            <B_SPV>1</B_SPV>
            <B_SPV_DOSTAWA>1</B_SPV_DOSTAWA>
            <B_MPV_PROWIZJA>1</B_MPV_PROWIZJA>
            <KorektaPodstawyOpodt>1</KorektaPodstawyOpodt>
            <TerminPlatnosci>2016-01-01</TerminPlatnosci>
            <K_10>0</K_10>
            <SprzedazVAT_Marza>0</SprzedazVAT_Marza>
        </SprzedazWiersz>
        <SprzedazWiersz>
            <LpSprzedazy>4</LpSprzedazy>
            <KodKrajuNadaniaTIN>EE</KodKrajuNadaniaTIN>
            <NrKontrahenta>d</NrKontrahenta>
            <NazwaKontrahenta>d</NazwaKontrahenta>
            <DowodSprzedazy>d</DowodSprzedazy>
            <DataWystawienia>2006-01-01</DataWystawienia>
            <DataSprzedazy>2006-01-01</DataSprzedazy>
            <TypDokumentu>WEW</TypDokumentu>
            <GTU_01>1</GTU_01>
            <WSTO_EE>1</WSTO_EE>
            <IED>1</IED>
            <TP>1</TP>
            <TT_WNT>1</TT_WNT>
            <TT_D>1</TT_D>
            <MR_T>1</MR_T>
            <MR_UZ>1</MR_UZ>
            <I_42>1</I_42>
            <I_63>1</I_63>
            <B_SPV>1</B_SPV>
            <B_SPV_DOSTAWA>1</B_SPV_DOSTAWA>
            <B_MPV_PROWIZJA>1</B_MPV_PROWIZJA>
            <KorektaPodstawyOpodt>1</KorektaPodstawyOpodt>
            <TerminPlatnosci>2016-01-01</TerminPlatnosci>
            <K_10>0</K_10>
            <SprzedazVAT_Marza>0</SprzedazVAT_Marza>
        </SprzedazWiersz>
        <SprzedazCtrl>
            <LiczbaWierszySprzedazy>0</LiczbaWierszySprzedazy>
            <PodatekNalezny>0</PodatekNalezny>
        </SprzedazCtrl>
    </Ewidencja>
</JPK>
```

and this is the desired csv output
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4tVR.png)

```
[row1]LpSprzedazy;KodKrajuNadaniaTIN;NrKontrahenta;NazwaKontrahenta;DowodSprzedazy;DataWystawienia;DataSprzedazy;TypDokumentu;GTU_01;WSTO_EE;IED;TP;TT_WNT;TT_D;MR_T;MR_UZ;I_42;I_63;B_SPV;B_SPV_DOSTAWA;B_MPV_PROWIZJA;KorektaPodstawyOpodt;TerminPlatnosci;K_10;SprzedazVAT_Marza
[row2]1;BB;a;a;a;1.01.2006;1.01.2006;WEW;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1.01.2016;0;0
[row3]2;CC;b;b;b;1.01.2006;1.01.2006;WEW;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1.01.2016;0;0
[row4]3;DD;c;c;c;1.01.2006;1.01.2006;WEW;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1.01.2016;0;0
[row5]4;EE;d;d;d;1.01.2006;1.01.2006;WEW;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1.01.2016;0;0
```

And this is what I'm getting:

```
[row1]KodFormularza;JPK_VAT
[row2]WariantFormularza;2
[row3]DataWytworzeniaJPK;2022-01-01T00:00:00Z
[row4]NazwaSystemu;a
[row5]CelZlozenia;2
[row6]KodUrzedu;1430
[row7]Rok;2022
[row8]Miesiac;1
[row9]Email;"!@"""
[row10]Telefon;a
[row11]LpSprzedazy;2
[row12]KodKrajuNadaniaTIN;CC
[row13]NrKontrahenta;b
[row14]NazwaKontrahenta;b
[row15]DowodSprzedazy;b
[row16]DataWystawienia;2006-01-01
[row17]DataSprzedazy;2006-01-01
[row18]TypDokumentu;WEW
[row19]GTU_01;1
[row20]WSTO_EE;1
[row21]IED;1
[row22]TP;1
[row23]TT_WNT;1
[row24]TT_D;1
[row25]MR_T;1
[row26]MR_UZ;1
[row27]I_42;1
[row28]I_63;1
[row29]B_SPV;1
[row30]B_SPV_DOSTAWA;1
[row31]B_MPV_PROWIZJA;1
[row32]KorektaPodstawyOpodt;1
[row33]TerminPlatnosci;2016-01-01
[row34]K_10;0
[row35]SprzedazVAT_Marza;0
[row36]LpSprzedazy;3
[row37]KodKrajuNadaniaTIN;DD
[row38]NrKontrahenta;c
[row39]NazwaKontrahenta;c
[row40]DowodSprzedazy;c
[row41]DataWystawienia;2006-01-01
[row42]DataSprzedazy;2006-01-01
[row43]TypDokumentu;WEW
[row44]GTU_01;1
[row45]WSTO_EE;1
[row46]IED;1
[row47]TP;1
[row48]TT_WNT;1
[row49]TT_D;1
[row50]MR_T;1
[row51]MR_UZ;1
[row52]I_42;1
[row53]I_63;1
[row54]B_SPV;1
[row55]B_SPV_DOSTAWA;1
[row56]B_MPV_PROWIZJA;1
[row57]KorektaPodstawyOpodt;1
[row58]TerminPlatnosci;2016-01-01
[row59]K_10;0
[row60]SprzedazVAT_Marza;0
[row61]LpSprzedazy;4
[row62]KodKrajuNadaniaTIN;EE
[row63]NrKontrahenta;d
[row64]NazwaKontrahenta;d
[row65]DowodSprzedazy;d
[row66]DataWystawienia;2006-01-01
[row67]DataSprzedazy;2006-01-01
[row68]TypDokumentu;WEW
[row69]GTU_01;1
[row70]WSTO_EE;1
[row71]IED;1
[row72]TP;1
[row73]TT_WNT;1
[row74]TT_D;1
[row75]MR_T;1
[row76]MR_UZ;1
[row77]I_42;1
[row78]I_63;1
[row79]B_SPV;1
[row80]B_SPV_DOSTAWA;1
[row81]B_MPV_PROWIZJA;1
[row82]KorektaPodstawyOpodt;1
[row83]TerminPlatnosci;2016-01-01
[row84]K_10;0
[row85]SprzedazVAT_Marza;0
[row86]LiczbaWierszySprzedazy;0
[row87]PodatekNalezny;0
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a *small* sample of the XML input, the desired CSV output, and the current CSV output - those are all text formats, so include the actual text in the question, not images.

Comment: I hope I edited everything correctly, sorry for any misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're dealing with xml, you should be better off using xpath instead. So I would modify your `Csv()` function to something along these lines:

```
$targets = $xml_content->xpath('//SprzedazWiersz');
$headers = $targets[0]->xpath('.//*');
$hdrs = array();

foreach ($headers as $header) {
    array_push($hdrs, $header->getName());
}

fputcsv($a, $hdrs);

foreach ($targets as $target){
    $row = $target->xpath('.//*/text()');
    fputcsv($a, $row);
    
}
```

And it should get you the expected output.

Comment: thank you! This puts me closer to what I was trying to do, but the data in the rows has to be all in the first cell separated by a semicolon, I was wondering if that is possible to do?

Comment: @Angelos Not sure I understand you: you want to end up with a csv file which has 25 headers, but only one cell in each data row?

Comment: My English is ok but when it comes to explaining technicalities I can see that I fail at that, I'll just screenshot the excel file, that should be faster than me trying to explain. Adding the photo above the desider output text.

Comment: @Angelos I think I understand you now - the code in the answer should give you exactly that. [See fiddle here.](https://3v4l.org/TlF7s)

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm trying to learn on my own and I've been struggling with this for hours, now I just have to understand why and how what you did works, again, thank you so much!